# How to center font on screen when numbers change from double to single digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have numbers displayed on screen in the game I'm creating and when the magnitude of the numbers change from double to single digits they shift in the wrong direction (left) creating a misalignment. Is it possible to have the font shift to the right or not shift at all and stay centered like the centering feature in spreadsheets?

```
def heroPortrait(name, hp):
    portrait = pygame.image.load(name + '.png')
    portrait.set_colorkey(WHITE)
    py_portrait = portrait.get_rect()
    py_portrait.topleft = (462, 502)
    fontHp = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
    renderHp = fontHp.render(hp, True, WHITE)
    renderHp_pos = renderHp.get_rect()
    renderHp_pos.center = (555, 578)
    screenSurf.blit(portrait, py_portrait.topleft) 
    screenSurf.blit(renderHp, renderHp_pos.center)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please illustrate your question by including the _relevant parts_ of your code. Like this, the question is too vague in order to be answered in a meaningful way and be helpful for you and the rest of the community. For more information, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy, when you draw your text, just subtract your screen width by your elements width divided by two.

```
screen.blit(screenWidth // 2 - myText.get_width(), screenHeight // 2 - myText.get_height())
```

This has lots of perks, it works on every screen size, and also adapts to width changes.

Comment: I didn't use screen width and height to align the text but the code works well enough for now.

Comment: Happy that it helped! You can always change the values later to whatever you want.

Comment: You probably meant: `(screenWidth // 2 - myText.get_width(), screenHeight // 2 - myText.get_height())`.

Comment: Yeah, thats actually correct, I pulled a part of it out from a project of mine and filled in the blanks. 
Ill edit

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a rect with the size of the screen which also gives you the center coords of the screen. Then you can create a rect with the size of the text surface, set its `center` coords to the `center` coords of the screen rect and use it as the blit position of the surface.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()  # A rect with the size of the screen.
clock = pg.time.Clock()
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 50)
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')

counter = 0

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    counter += 1
    # Render a new text surface each frame.
    text_surface = FONT.render(str(counter), True, BLUE)
    # Set the center of the text rect to the center of the screen_rect.
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    # Blit the surface at the rect's topleft coords.
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

---

Here'a left-aligned version which doesn't jitter. I use the average width of the numbers and the length of the number string to adjust the blit position.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()  # A rect with the size of the screen.
clock = pg.time.Clock()
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 42)
# Calculate the average width of the numbers.
AVERAGE_WIDTH = FONT.size('0123456789')[0] / 10
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
KEYS = {pg.K_u: 500, pg.K_i: 5000, pg.K_o: 50000, pg.K_p: 500000}

counter = 1

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            # Press u, i, o or p to increase the counter.
            counter += KEYS.get(event.key, 0)

    counter += 1

    text_surface = FONT.render(str(counter), True, BLUE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(midleft=screen_rect.center)
    # Calculate the approximate half width of the text surface.
    half_width = len(str(counter)) * AVERAGE_WIDTH / 2
    # And subtract it from the x coord.
    text_rect.x -= half_width

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
    pg.draw.line(screen, BLUE, (0, screen_rect.h/2), (screen_rect.w, screen_rect.h/2))
    pg.draw.line(screen, BLUE, (screen_rect.w/2, 0), (screen_rect.w/2, screen_rect.h))
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```